# This Javascript if statement won't run when using not operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return an object with each letter from a string as a key, and each key's value being the amount of times that letter appears.

The if statement doesn't seem to execute, I think it's a problem with the not operator because I can get it to execute if I remove it and put the letter in the object so that it evaluates to true.

```
function multipleLetterCount(str){    
    var countObj = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        //Why won't this if statement run???
        if(!str[i] in countObj){
            countObj[str[i]] = 1;
        } else {
            countObj[str[i]]++; 
        }
    }
    return countObj;
}

multipleLetterCount("aaa")
```

It returns {a: NaN}

Comment: `!` has a higher precedence than `in`, so use parentheses to enforce the correct order. Try `if (!(str[i] in countObj))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your condition with the negation operator (`!`)

```
if(!(str[i] in countObj))
```

**Or even better, invert your condition:**

```
if (str[i] in countObj) {
    countObj[str[i]]++;
} else {
    countObj[str[i]] = 1; 
}
```